# I need to show a badge on Material chip at the right top. How can I easily do it?

Tags: android, material-components-android, material-components, android-chips

Im trying this way

```
    override fun draw(canvas: Canvas) {
        super.draw(canvas)
        val viewWidth = width.toFloat()
        val padding = chipEndPadding
        canvas.drawOval(viewWidth - padding, padding, viewWidth, padding + padding, paint)
    }
```

But it doesnt seem to be showing up probably because of the chipDrawable. Any way to accomplish this. This method works for all other views, But Not chip!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [**`BadgeDrawable`**](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/BadgeDrawable.md) provided by the Material Components Library.

In your layout:

```
    <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
        android:id="@+id/chip"
```

Then:

```
    chip.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            BadgeDrawable badgeDrawable = BadgeDrawable.create(MainActivity.this);
            badgeDrawable.setNumber(4);
            badgeDrawable.setVerticalOffset(25);
            badgeDrawable.setHorizontalOffset(15);
            BadgeUtils.attachBadgeDrawable(badgeDrawable, chip, null);

            chip.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
        }
    });
```

[image]

Comment: AndroidStudio shows an error for BadgeUtils as this class is annotated as @RestrictTo(Scope.LIBRARY), however it compiles without problems and seems to work...

Answer (score 0):

`getViewTreeObserver` did not work well for me and caused some problems but
`View.post()` method worked much easier :

```
public void showBadgeOnView(View view, int someNumber, Context context) {
 BadgeDrawable badgeDrawable = BadgeDrawable.create(context);
 badgeDrawable.setNumber(someNumber);
 view.post(() ->BadgeUtils.attachBadgeDrawable(badgeDrawable, view, null));
}
```